# Proving convergence of the square root of a convergent sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $(a_n)$ be a convergent sequence of positive real numbers with limit $l ≥ 0$. Prove that the
sequence $(\sqrt{a_n})$ is convergent, with limit $\sqrt{l}$.

I have tried using the formal definition but I am not really sure where to start.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Let $a,b\geq 0$. Then,
$$|\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}|\leq \sqrt{|a-b|}.$$